# ROW_NUMBER() to be applied only for top N records

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, row-number

I have a scenario to get the zero-indexed value for a result set based on the `Id` column. I can achieve this by `ROW_NUMBER()`. But there was a slight change in the expected behavior now.

The expectation is, for the **top five records** only the `IndexValue` need to be displayed, for the remaining entries the `IndexValue` should be `NULL`.

To achieve this, I have set the `IndexValue` by `ROW_NUMBER()`, push into a table variable `@PopulateValues`, then using `UPDATE` I get the expected result as shown below:

**What I have tried:**

```
-- Actual Table in database
DECLARE @OriginalTable TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1), [Name] VARCHAR (255));
INSERT INTO @OriginalTable ([Name]) VALUES 
('Name 01'), ('Name 02'), ('Name 03'), ('Name 04'), ('Name 05'), 
('Name 06'), ('Name 07'), ('Name 08'), ('Name 09'), ('Name 10'), 
('Name 11'), ('Name 12'), ('Name 13'), ('Name 14'), ('Name 15');

-- Table variable for the populate calculation
DECLARE @PopulateValues TABLE (Id INT, [Name] VARCHAR (255), IndexValue INT NULL);
INSERT INTO @PopulateValues (Id, [Name], IndexValue)
SELECT Id, [Name], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) - 1 AS IndexValue
FROM @OriginalTable;

UPDATE @PopulateValues SET IndexValue = NULL WHERE IndexValue >= 5;

SELECT * FROM @PopulateValues;
```

By this approach, I am able to achieve my expectation, but is there any other way I can apply the `ROW_NUMBER()` only for `TOP N` records while `SELECT`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression in the query:

```
SELECT Id, Name, CASE WHEN IndexValue < 5 THEN IndexValue END AS IndexValue
FROM   (SELECT Id, Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) - 1 AS IndexValue
        FROM   @OriginalTable) t
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a CASE statement along with a subquery like so:

```
INSERT INTO @PopulateValues (Id, [Name], IndexValue)
SELECT x.[Id], x.[Name], CASE WHEN x.IndexValue < 5 THEN x.IndexValue ELSE NULL END AS [IndexValue]
FROM
(
SELECT Id, [Name], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) - 1 AS IndexValue
FROM @OriginalTable;
) AS x
```

Answer (score 2):

As I found one more possible way using [Logical Function - IIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (starting with SQL Server 2012), so the query will be:

```
SELECT Id, [Name], IIF(IndexValue < 5, IndexValue, NULL) AS IndexValue 
FROM  ( SELECT Id, Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) - 1 AS IndexValue
        FROM @OriginalTable ) Q
```